# Ways to squeeze $e$ by hand

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, recreational-mathematics

> Let $a$ and $b$ be the lower and upper bound of [$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), respectively. Both $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers. Without using a calculator and without knowing the value of $e$, find $a$ and $b$ where $b-a<10^{-6}$.

---

So, we are asked to find

$$a<e<b$$

where $b-a<10^{-6}$. Using the series expansion for $e$, I'm able to find both $a$ and $b$, namely

$$a=\sum_{n=0}^{10}\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{6235301}{3628800}$$

and

$$b=\sum_{n=0}^{9}\frac{1}{n!}=\frac{62353}{36288}$$

but I have to confirm my calculation for $n=11$ and $n=12$ so that the value of summation is more stable. We then have

$$b-a=\frac{1}{3628800}<10^{-6}$$

I also found another way using the definition of $e$ to obtain other values of $a$ and $b$ by using this inequality:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x < e < \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$$

Though it's *doable*, this method is very time consuming and very tedious. Is there another way? If any, an efficient one?

Comment: The way you've defined $a$, it's impossible for it to be an upper bound of $e$. Every partial sum of that series is smaller than $e$.

Answer (score 4):

The "tail" when we truncate the usual series for $e$ just after the term $\frac{1}{9!}$ is
$$\frac{1}{10!}+\frac{1}{11!}+\frac{1}{12!}+\cdots.$$ 
This sum is less than the sum of the infinite geometric series
$$\frac{1}{10!}\left(1+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{11^2}+\cdots\right),$$
which is $\frac{11}{10\cdot 10!}$. This is less than our target error.

So we can take $a=\sum_0^9 \frac{1}{k!}$ and $b=a+\frac{11}{10\cdot 10!}$.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about a way to compute **by hand**, not just symbolically.

Comment: There does remain the unpleasantness of summing by hand. But a large part of that has already been done by OP.

Comment: @user21820 "By hand" computations are usually symbolic. These are actual expressions which yield rational numbers, and one can verify by hand that $a-b<10^{-6}$, so it fits the criteria in my view.

Comment: @user21820 ...Then again, if "calculation" is not necessary as long as a valid rational number is given, $b=10^{-6}\lfloor 10^6e\rfloor$ and $a=b+10^{-6}$ will also do the job, without having to know anything about $e$ itself.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Oh alright I see how you've interpreted the question differently. I actually thought the asker meant to compute the digits.